# R how to do division from one dataframe to another dataframe corresponding column name

Tags: r, dataframe

Hello I wanted devide the one dataframe value from another datframe by its corrsponding column

Df

```
   std1 std2 std3 std4
     1    4    4   10
     2    10   6   20
```

df2

```
   std1 std2 std3 std4
    1     2   2    10
```

output=

```
    std1 std2 std3 std4
     1    2    2   1
     2    5    3   2
```

I have tried output=Df/df2
I got a error anyone help me to resolve this

Answer (score 2):

As direct division is possible only for dataframes with same dimension, you can repeat the rows in `df2`.

```
df1/df2[rep(nrow(df2), nrow(df1)), ]

#  std1 std2 std3 std4
#1    1    2    2    1
#2    2    5    3    2
```

Some other alternatives to this are -

```
df1[] <- Map(`/`, df1, df2)
df1[] <- purrr::map2(df1, df2, `/`)
df1 <- purrr::map2_df(df1, df2, `/`)
```

If the column names are not always ordered, you can first arrange any one of the dataframe with `df2 <- df2[names(df1)]` before using the above answer.

Comment: I am getting an  error ` Error in FUN(left, right) : non-numeric argument to binary operator`

Comment: Check `class` of the columns. Are they numeric? you can use `str(df1)` and `str(df2)` to check that.

Comment: df1 row names are in string and columns values are int

Comment: If you have trouble implementing the answer to your data, I'll suggest to share a reproducible example of your data using `dput`.

Answer (score 2):

When `df2` has only one row `sweep` could be used:

```
sweep(Df, 2, unlist(df2), "/")
#  std1 std2 std3 std4
#1    1    2    2    1
#2    2    5    3    2
```

or using `col`:

```
Df / df2[col(Df)]
#  std1 std2 std3 std4
#1    1    2    2    1
#2    2    5    3    2
```

Data:

```
Df <- read.table(header=TRUE, text="std1 std2 std3 std4
     1    4    4   10
     2    10   6   20")

df2 <- read.table(header=TRUE, text="std1 std2 std3 std4
    1     2   2    10")
```

Comment: I Tried above code I am getting error **Error in FUN(left, right) : non-numeric argument to binary operator**

Comment: What data have you used? I provided the data I used now in the Answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a S3 class solution.

```
`/.data.frame` <- function(x, y){
  if(is.null(dim(y))){
    x[] <- Map('/', x, y)
  } else {
    i <- intersect(names(x), names(y))
    if(length(i) == 0){
      xname <- deparse(substitute(x))
      yname <- deparse(substitute(y))
      warn <- sprintf("%s and %s have no common columns, returning %s", xname, yname, xname)
      warning(warn)
    } else{
      x[i] <- Map('/', x[i], y[i])
    }
  }
  x
}

Df / df2
#  std1 std2 std3 std4
#1    1    2    2    1
#2    2    5    3    2

df3 <- as.data.frame(matrix(1:3, ncol = 1))
Df / df3
#  std1 std2 std3 std4
#1    1    4    4   10
#2    2   10    6   20
#Warning message:
#In `/.data.frame`(Df, df3) :
#  Df and df3 have no common columns, returning Df

Df / 1:2
#  std1 std2 std3 std4
#1    1    2    4    5
#2    2    5    6   10
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this work:

```
df1/rbind(df2,df2)
  std1 std2 std3 std4
1    1    2    2    1
2    2    5    3    2
```

Data used:

```
df1
  std1 std2 std3 std4
1    1    4    4   10
2    2   10    6   20
df2
  std1 std2 std3 std4
1    1    2    2   10
```

Comment: in this index row name matters? my df1 row name are in string, and  I am getting error not an equal size dataframe

Comment: @ShrilaxmiMS, are your dataframes of same columns?

Comment: Yes same columns